# Getting wrong timestame in MPRemoteCommandEvent iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting wrong timestamp when try to print previous event of `MPRemoteCommandCenter`!

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onPreviousTrackRemoteCommand(_:)))
```

```
@objc func onPreviousTrackRemoteCommand(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
    print("\(event.timestamp)___\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
    return .noSuchContent
}
```

Result:

```
600086691.979996___1578393891.980029
600086692.555986___1578393892.55602
600086692.716319___1578393892.7163548
```

In above result event time is not near to current timestamp!!

Comment: The timestamp is correct. Its Unix timestamp. You can convert it to human readable format here: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: I know it's unix timestamp, and i don't want to convert it

Comment: ahh! Sorry i got it wrong. i will delete my answer then

Comment: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1578393891.980029) == Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 600086691.979996). Strangely, it's a TimeStamp from 2001, not 1970. Could have been said in documentation of the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first output:

```
Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1578393891.980029)
```

and

```
Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 600086691.979996)
```

points to the same date ~2020-01-07 10:44:51 +0000 (almost since the decimal after seconds are slightly different)

It's not said in the documentation of [`timestamp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandevent/1616784-timestamp) but it's a timestamp from 2001, not 1970.

Comment: way to go Apple...just keep messing things up